# Doble llamada Ajax con Vanilla

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

LLevo mucho timepo enrredada con este código, por eso recurro a foros, 
Quiero hacer como una guía de películas pero con la información sacada de una API, se que debo tener dos llamadas Ajax Una con la que llena mi lista de personajes (10) Ahora cuando hago clic en cada uno de los personajes me de titulo, imagen y reseña de una película en la que aparecen, (Información sacada de la API) la información aparece en la misma página, y se que la llamo mediante Ajax, pero aquí esta mi error, no sé como darle atributos a los personajes(que tenga la información de las películas) así que cuando de clic me muestre estas imagenes.

Dejo mi código, y agradezco Infinito la ayuda

```
function personajes(url, callback) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

try {
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
} catch(err) {

return;
}
callback(data);
}
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

personajes("https://swapi.co/api/people/", function(data, el) {


var persons=data.results;
var html ;

var container = document.querySelector(".text ul");

for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){

var item = container.innerHTML += "<li><a id='ajax_item' onClick= 'obtenerDatos()' > "+ persons[i].name + "</a></li>";
//var one = container.innerHTML += persons[i].films;


}
document.getElementbyId("ajax_item").setAttribute( 'persons[i].films', JSON.stringify(el.films));

})



function obtenerDatos(event) {



var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

try {
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
} catch(err) {

return;
}

}
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Necesito que funcione como este código, pero en lista y con una película. Agradezco mucho la ayuda, he batallado bastante es esto.

```
var response;
document.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (document.readyState== "complete")
  {
    personajes();

    document.querySelector('.text').onclick=peliculas;
  }
}


function personajes ()
{
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if (httpRequest.readyState ===4)
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200){
        //console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
        response=JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);


        var list = document.querySelector(".text");
        list.innerHTML = ""

        response.results.forEach(function(el)
        {
          option=document.createElement("option");
          option.innerHTML= el.name;
          option.setAttribute('films', JSON.stringify(el.films))
          list.appendChild(option);
        })


      }
    }
  }

  httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://swapi.co/api/<peo></peo>ple/');
  httpRequest.send();
}


function peliculas(ev)
{
  selected=ev.target;
  films=JSON.parse(selected.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('films'));

  var list=document.querySelector('#results');
  list.innerHTML= ""

  films.forEach(function(url)
  {
    console.log(43, url);
    var httpRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
      if (httpRequest.readyState ===4)
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200){

        film= JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(film.title);

        li=document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML=film.title;
        list.appendChild(li);

      }

    }
  }

    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  })
}
```